# Getting error Show::gtype: when trying to render a CartesianMap expression as graphics

Tags: plotting, graphics, warning-messages

I wrote this code for calculate the streamline for a airfoil

```
Clear[F, F1, F2, F3, F4, dx, dy, r0, w, z, Z]
JoukowskiFun[dx_, dy_] := 
  Module[{},
    r0 = Sqrt[(1 - dx)^(2) + (0 - dy)^(2)];
    Z1 = (z + Sqrt[z^(2) - 4])/2;
    Z2 = (z - Sqrt[z^(2) - 4])/2;
    Z3 = (-z - Sqrt[z^(2) - 4])/2;
    Z3 = (-z + Sqrt[z^(2) - 4])/2; 
    w[z_] = r0*z + dx + dy*I;
    F[z_] = z + (1/z);
    F1[z_] = F[w[Z1]];
    F2[z_] = F[w[Z2]];
    F3[z_] = F[w[Z3]];
    F4[z_] = F[w[Z4]];]
```

I need graph their functions but in particular `F1[z]`

```
JoukowskiPlot := 
  Module[{}, 
   gr1 = 
     CartesianMap[F1, {0.00001, 3.20001, 0.2}, {0.00001, 0.60001, 0.1},
       PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}, 
       DisplayFunction -> Identity];
   Show[gr1, 
     Ticks -> {Range[-2, 2, 2], Range[-2, 2, 1]}, 
     PlotRange -> {{-3.2, 3.2}, {-0.75, 2.05}}, 
     AspectRatio -> (2.8/6.2), 
     DisplayFunction -> $DisplayFunction];]

JoukowskiFun[-1/10, 1/10]
JoukowskiPlot;
```

But I have this error:

> Show::gtype: CartesianMap is not a type of graphics.

Comment: Your code works great in version 5.2 if you load the Graphics ComplexMap package first.  Unfortunately as of Version 6, support for that ended.  ParametricPlot sort of works, but not as well.  Are you using an old version of MMA, or did you just find this code somewhere?

Comment: [A related question.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/119516)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's too localized.

Answer (score 2):

CartesianMap is not a built-in Mathematica function. If I understand you correctly, you can use `ParametricPlot` instead:

```
JoukowskiPlot := Module[{},
  gr1 = ParametricPlot[ReIm[F1[x + I y]],
    {x, 0.0000, 3.2000},
    {y, 0.0000, 0.6000},
    PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}
    ];
  Show[gr1,
   Ticks -> {Range[-2, 2, 2], Range[-2, 2, 1]},
   PlotRange -> {{-3.2, 3.2}, {-0.75, 2.05}},
   AspectRatio -> (2.8/6.2)
   ]
  ]
```

Note that I also removed a semicolon at the end of the `Show` command. Leaving it there would lead to an empty plot.